# Как проверить на совместимость json с моделью?

Tags: java, android, json

Дело в том что в bundle не передается Object через серилиализацию. Поэтому я решил передать String который содержи json, а затем его обратно спарсить в Model.

Но дело в том что у меня 1 окно может работать с 3 моделями, так как адаптеры у них одинаковые. И чтобы не создавать 3 разных адаптера, я решил все сделать в 1 активити и с 1 адаптером.

У меня есть 3 ModelA, ModelB, ModelC. Как узнать к какой модели отностится данный json?

Библиотеку использую Gson

`compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'`

Comment: Почему у вас не получается? Покажите как пробовали и что из этого выходило.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интересная задача...

Первое что приходит в голову, это передавать в `Bundle` 2 объекта, один показывает тип json, а второй собственно сам json:

```
//отправка
ModelA modelA;
bundle.putInt("type", 1); //указываем тип
bundle.putString("json", gson.toJson(modelA, ModelA.class); //пихаем строку json

//приемник
int type=bundle.getInt("type")
String jsonString=bundle.getString("json");
Model model;
switch(type) {
   case 1:
      model=gson.parseJson(jsonString, ModelA.class);
      break;
   case 2:
      model=gson.parseJson(jsonString, ModelB.class);
      break;
   case 3:
      model=gson.parseJson(jsonString, ModelC.class);
      break;
   default:
      throw new IllegaArgumentException("blah-blah);
}
```

**Update**

Вспомнил, как я решил аналогичную задачу в своем прожекте. Создаем кастомный Gson/json сериализатор, задачей которого будет вставка при сериализации типа объекта и его использование при десериализации:

```
public class ModelSerializer<T extends Model> implements JsonSerializer<T>, JsonDeserializer<T> {

    private static final String CLASS_META_KEY = "clz";
    private final Gson defaultGson;

    public ModelSerializer() {
        defaultGson=new Gson(); //нужен голый экземпляр Gson
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(T src, Type typeOfSrc,
                                 JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonElement element=null;
        if (src == null) {
            return element;
        }
            if (src instanceof ModelA)
                element = context.serialize(src, ModelA.class);
            else if (src instanceof ModelB)
                element = context.serialize(src, ModelB.class);
            else if (src instanceof ModelC)
                element = context.serialize(src, ModelC.class);
            //добавляем в Json свойство - полное название класса
            element.getAsJsonObject().addProperty(CLASS_META_KEY, src.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        return element;
    }

@Override
    public T deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Class<?> clz;
        T model;

        JsonObject object = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        if(object.has(CLASS_META_KEY)) { //определяем тип
            String className = object.get(CLASS_META_KEY_RECORD).getAsString();
            try {
                clz = Class.forName(className);
            } catch (Exception e) {
               //blah-blah
            }
            model = context.deserialize(jsonElement, clz); 
        }
        else {
            model=defaultGson.fromJson(jsonElement, typeOfT);
        }
        return model;
    }
}
```

Теперь втыкаем этот обработчик в Gson:

```
 gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Model.class, new ModelSerializer<Model>())
            .serializeNulls()
            //.setPrettyPrinting() //for debugging
            .disableHtmlEscaping() 
            .create();
```

далее пользуемся этим экземпляром Gson для сериализации и десериализации.

При таком подходе весь цирк с конями с заданием типа в отдельном `int type` и проч. не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант. Берем [RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java). Не стесняемся, фабрика в репозитории самого gson'а, просто в библиотеку не включена.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapterFactory(
         RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory
             .of(Model.class)
             .registerSubtype(ModelA.class)
             .registerSubtype(ModelB.class)
             .registerSubtype(ModelC.class)).create();
Model model = new ModelA();
//Сериализуем
String json = gson.toJson(model);

//Десериализуем
Model parsed = gson.fromJson(json, Model.class);
```

или даже

```
List<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new ModelA());
list.add(new ModelB());
list.add(new ModelC());
//Сериализуем
String json = gson.toJson(list);

//Десериализуем
List<Model> parsedList = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Model>>(){}.getType());
```

ЗЫ Есть вроде бы какой-то баг, но проявляется на сложных случаях (то ли поле type в классе есть, то ли еще какая-то экзотика, по ошибке можно погуглить, фикс есть).